# svg problem with mouse event when viewbox is negative

Tags: svg

I use SVG to draw a geographic map. But when viewbox is with negative values - mouse event did not work. Please review a fiddle bellow:

```html
<svg 
 id="svg" class="mapNavSVG"
 width="100%" 
 viewBox="27.7333333 -43.2233334 0.2183334 0.0566667"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"  
 shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
 >
  <rect x="27.7333333" y="-43.2233334" width="0.2183334" height="0.0566667" style="fill:#0059b3;" />
  <rect onClick="alert('Test!');" x="27.9408" y="-43.1944975" width="0.006" height="0.006" style="fill:yellow;" />
  </svg>
```

Values are real GPS coordinates. And as you can see - when click on yellow rectangle - nothing happened.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: 08.01.2018
afer some comments here and additional research i've found that reason for that issue is small real (non integer) numbers. In chrome problem is fixed but in firefox problem still presist in version 64, even that there is [issue log in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396642). It will be too hard for me to scale all SVG elements in my map because i've get them from GIS sofftware.
Thanks to all for help.

Comment: When I click on the yellow box, it alerts 'Test!'...  I'm on Chrome 71...

Answer (score 5):

These are browser-dependent computational errors. In the following snippet, I have set a px width and height for the `<svg>` to get comparable results. The width reported for the yellow rectangle should match when returned from `.getBoundingClientRect()` and when computed from `.getBBox()`, multiplied with the scale value from `.getScreenCTM()`:

```js
var rect = document.querySelector('rect:last-child');
var size = rect.getBBox().width;
console.log('local width:', size);
var scale = rect.getScreenCTM().a;
console.log('screen scale:', scale, 'screen width:', size*scale);
console.log('bounding rect width', rect.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

```html
<svg 
 id="svg" class="mapNavSVG"
 width="500px" height="100px"
 viewBox="27.7333333 -43.2233334 0.2183334 0.0566667"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"  
 shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
 >
  <rect x="27.7333333" y="-43.2233334" width="0.2183334" height="0.0566667" style="fill:#0059b3;" />
  <rect x="27.9408" y="-43.1944975" width="0.006" height="0.006" style="fill:yellow;" />
  </svg>
```

In Chromium 71/Debian, the results (more or less) match: 10.588px to 10.589px.

In Firefox 60esr/Debian and Firefox 64/Windows, they don't: 10.589px to 29.416px for the bounding rect (also reported in the dev tools).

Edge and IE11 compute 10.655px, but the bounding rect has a value of (sic!) 1775.275px. At least the mouse event capture seems to get the area correctly.

What can you learn from that? Very small numbers lead to large errors on some browsers. From other questions on the site and previous experiences I'd say it is a good idea to not size elements with values below 1px. If you scale every number with 1000, the errors disappear:

```html
<svg 
 id="svg" class="mapNavSVG"
 width="100%" 
 viewBox="27733.3333 -43223.3334 218.3334 56.6667"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"  
 shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
 >
  <rect x="27733.3333" y="-43223.3334" width="218.3334" height="56.6667" style="fill:#0059b3;" />
  <rect onClick="alert('Test!');" x="27940.8" y="-43194.4975" width="6" height="6" style="fill:yellow;" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: Hmm Firefox 64 [should be better](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396642)

Comment: well, scale to 1000 seem fine for me! I'll try it tomorow on production... i've never know that small numbers will cause such problems. Thank you @ccprog

Comment: Scaling solve the problem. Now i must figure it out hoe to scale entyre map elements - i have a lot of PATH elements.